# И январю декабрь дышит в спину(?!)

Tags: грамотная-речь

Ходит по интернету ролик со стихотворением Ирины Самариной "А там, на небе - тоже суета". Хорошее стихотворение, но меня смутила фраза "И январю декабрь дышит в спину". Мы уже обсуждали на этом сайте две системы восприятия времени: "мы стоим в потоке времени" (время движется, январь наступает за декабрем) и "мы движемся во времени" (переходим из декабря в январь — тут  декабрь стоит **за** январем). Но в стихотворении явно время движется ("дышит в спину" говорят о догоняющем). Получается, что декабрь идет за январем.(?!)

Прав ли я в этих рассуждениях? А может быть на небе время движется в обратную сторону?

Дополнение

У меня в подсознании сидит стихотворение Тютчева из школьной программы: *Зима недаром злится,//Прошла её пора –//Весна в окно стучится//И гонит со двора.* По этой модели январь должен гнать со двора декабрь, толкать его в спину, а изгоняемый декабрь никак не может дышать январю в спину.

Comment: Простите за занудство, а почему у Вас "?!" в скобках? :)

Comment: Имел в виду в тексте, а не в заголовке. Получается, что вне скобок вообще нет знака препинания.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Вопрос интересный. Как, по-вашему, надо писать "?!", если это не вопрос, а замечание в скобках? После точки?

Comment: Немного странно выглядит)) Но если без этого никак, то я думаю, что лучше перед точкой (как, например, и в случае с кавычками).

Answer (score 3):

Вы правы, тут что-то не так.

Январь впереди, но он ещё не начинал свой путь: он ждёт эстафетную палочку от декабря; а декабрь идёт к январю,  слабеет, его всё меньше. В спину январю он может дохнуть (или дыхнуть?) разок разве что 31 декабря, когда месяцы встретятся и январь начнёт двигаться. А декабрь кончится. Это будет последнее дыхание декабря в уходящем году.

Неужели этот смысл заложен?)

Comment: Предыдущий прокрался за спину предстоящему и дохнул: поехали! :)

Comment: Передача эстафетной палочки? Екатерина, Ваше  объяснение спасает автора. Вы продемонстрировали образец образного мышления, которое в данном случае оказалось лучшим инструментом, чем логика. Однако, замечу: спортивные ассоциации плохо сочетаются с общим тоном этого стихотворения.

Comment: Согласна, это очевидно. Я, к сожалению, прочитала стихотворение после того, как дала ответ. Формулируя ответ,  я присмаривалась только к фразе, предложенной для анализа.

Answer (score 2):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кажется, у декабря в таком виде нет проблем с нюханием спины января. :)

Однако если представить себе год в виде отрезка, то декабрю, действительно, дышать уже не в кого (за ним *ничто*):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но год — это ведь не отрезок, пройдя который мы погрузимся в ничто, верно? Равно как и после двенадцати часов ночи время не исчезнет, а начнет свой цикл заново. Поэтому, как мне кажется, рассматривая год как временной цикл, мы можем себе представить, как *январю декабрь дышит в спину*.

Comment: Теперь представьте, в какую сторону это колесо крутится. Если январь наступает после  декабря, то против часовой стрекли, верно? Так где у январе спина? Она повернута в сторону февраля (если, конечно, он не движется спиной вперед). Как же декабрь туда дышит?

Comment: А если Вы представляете себе это как циферблат, по которому движется стрелка, то как решить где у января спина? Почему она повернута именно в сторону декабря?  По-моему, он стоит к декабрю боком, к нам лицом.

Comment: Я не понимаю, почему в бесконечном цикле, которым мы привыкли отмерять бесконечный поток времени, вы допускаете возможность движения в обратную сторону. Да пусть год называется хоть _бобом_, в котором 2 _шреза_ (в каждом из которых 182 восхода солнца), на время это никак влиять не будет, оно будет течь дальше, вперед. _Шрез_ А будет перетекать в _шрез_ Б, который, в свою очередь, будет перетекать опять в _шрез_ А. От _шреза_ А до _шреза_ А — 1 _боб_ (364 восхода солнца). И вы теперь говорите, что _шрез_ Б перетекает не в следуюший _шрез_ А, а в предыдущий.

Comment: Если бы у нас остались только пустые понятия этих _шрезов_ (без содержания временни как потока, движущегося вперед), то можно было бы сказать, что _шрез_ Б идет назад, к _шрезу_ А (ведь логически он там есть), но эти _шрезы_, как и месяцы, тесно связаны с нашим восприятием времени, поэтому _шрез_ Б идет не к предыдущему _шрезу_ А, а к следующему. Таким образом, если мы не страдаем (как Юм, к примеру) отрицанием причинности, то верим, что за Б идет не предыдущее А, а следующее А. Поэтому это самое Б (декабрь) спокойно дышит следующему А (январю) у нас в голове.

Comment: Спина у января — это условное обозначение начала (спины) определенного потока времени (января) в будущем, которое заканчивается пупком (концом определенного (условного) потока времени).

Comment: В общем говоря, если вы не согласны с моим пониманием вашего вопроса, то, значит, я его и не понял. Пусть будет эстафетная палочка.

Comment: Если слишком серьезно относиться к этому вопросу, то окажется, что прошлого нет, будущее еще не наступило, а уловить настоящее не представляется возможным.

Comment: @СтепанПопов, Ваш ответ очень хорош! Всё очень толково, просто и доступно. Я тоже хотела нарисовать круг и отрезок, но не знала как. Спасибо Вам.

Comment: @ЕкатеринаКаштанова, спасибо Вам за отзыв.

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку мне тоже трудно представить себе геометрически исходный вариант (декабрь не может подгонять январь сзади), предлагаю другой:

> ... и с январём декабрь играет в кёрлинг...

Comment: +1 за чувство юмора!

Answer (score 1):

С подсказки Екатерины Каштановой у меня сложилась картинка передачи эстафетной палочки от одного месяца к другому (эстафетный бег). Месяц, который получает палочку, бежит свой отрезок пути и "правит миром", затем приближается к следующему, "дышит ему в спину" и передает палочку. Только таким образом можно объяснить слова о том, что декабрь дышит в спину январю. Однако замечу, что спортивные ассоциации плохо сочетаются с общим тоном этого стихотворения.

Answer (score 1):

Можно представить, что зрители сидят в зале театра (пусть будет Моссовета). Выходил декабрь, поморозил, разложил снег и проч. И ушёл за сцену. Зрители видят декабрьские декорации. В это время в левом портале готовится к выходу январь, пока ему рано выходить, но декабрь стоит и дышит ему в спину (как бы готовит смену себе, он пока хозяин сцены). Enter январь. И расставляет свои декорации, становится новым хозяином. Логика, конечно, страдает, но это уже не спортивная метафора с "эстафетной палочкой", которая вполне логична).

Но если серьезно, полагаю, что автор не задумывался. Есть часто обсуждаемый (в т.ч. зрителями "Служебного романа") классический пример у Пастернака "ты прекрасна без извилин". Насколько помню, кто-то из комментаторов склоняется к тому, что автор иногда может не заметить...

Answer (score 1):

Если отбросить версию об ошибке автора, то самая убедительная, на мой взгляд, такая: январю 2018 дышит в спину декабрь 2018. Год только начался, но скоротечность времени ощущается. Аналогично можно сказать: "И молодости старость дышит в спину".

Comment: Интересная мысль, но не по теме стихотворения. Там на небе происходит предновогодняя суета, вот-вот наступит январь (2019 года , конечно).

Comment: @М_Г тогда придерживаюсь версии об ошибке автора.

Answer (score 0):

Может быть, так:
*И январю 2019 года дышит в спину декабрь 2018 года.*

Comment: Что Вы хотели сказать? То, что январь следующего года, а  декабрь предыдущего, — ясно всем.

Comment: Ну да. Январь готов начать движение, в то время как  декабрь уже рядом, за  его спиной. Его время заканчивается, и он дышит январю в спину. Мне кажется, что автор вряд ли стал бы вкладывать в эту строку особенную философию и останавливать на ней  внимание читателя, потому что центральной здесь является другая тема, а именно люди и ангелы на фоне Нового года.

Answer (score 0):

Кажется, понятно, что имелось в виду. *И X-у Y-ек дышит в спину* значит 'Y (декабрь) вскоре догонит X (январь) — догонит тот момент, когда происходит смена месяца'. Время летит так быстро, что декабрь стремительно сменяется январем. Порядок вещей не нарушен.

Comment: У меня (с подсказки Екатерины) сложилась картинка передачи эстафетной палочки, но до этого никак не мог понять, как и куда два месяца бегут наперегонки.

Comment: @М_Г тут же не "наперегонки", а просто идея скорости. А в круговороте времени декабрь действительно стоит перед январем.

Comment: Идея скорости? Декабрь бежит быстрее, чем январь?

Comment: @М_Г декабрь скоро сменится январем.

Comment: Вот Вы на смене, на посту, скоро я Вас сменю. Каким образом Вы мне дышите в спину?

Comment: @М_Г нельзя менять стилистику, метафоры к этому чувствительны. Месяц — это нематериальная вещь, она, если вам угодно, вообще дышать не может.

Comment: Похоже, у нас нет взимопонимания в этом вопросе.

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может, такая иллюстрация поможет продвинуться в решении этого парадокса. :) Скажем, время — бесконечный поток, состоящий из людей, а люди, в свою очередь, — месяцы. Из этого бесконечного потока мы выдернули определенное количество — число, а именно 15 человек. Люди здесь стоят в очереди, смотрят, так сказать, в будущее.

Для того чтобы декабрь дышал январю в спину, он должен стоять позади января. Вот тут начинается проблема: в каком смысле позади? Отсюда также начинаются все проблемы с декабрем, который бежит быстрее января. Открыв календарь, мы увидим, что декабрь никак не может стоять позади (сразу после) января, иначе получается, что сначала идет январь, а затем декабрь, после которого идет… февраль? Как раз таки в случае календаря стрелочка поменяет свое направление! Сначала будет стоять январь (он будет теперь первый в очереди, и головы всех повернутся к нему, так как с него начнется отчет всех остальных в очереди), но январю в таком случае декабрь точно не сможет никуда дышать, потому что позади (сразу после) января стоит в очереди февраль. Но ведь это не так, стрелочка ведет в будущее, головы повернуты туда же. Отчет также начинается с того, кто впереди, ближе к будущему (он там где-то в бесконечности, в каком-то первоначале), а раз так, то и декабрь в таком случае стоит позади будущего января и дышит ему в спину.

Comment: Ничего не понимаю... Почему позади это сразу после?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой, а как вы себе представляете человека, который стоит в конце очереди и дышит в спину первому? Как сильно он должен дышать?

Comment: _Получается, что декабрь идет за январем?!_ — М_Г ведь не просто так задал такой вопрос с, казалось бы, очевидным ответом. Он, как мне кажется, и подразумевал _сразу после_ января. И неспроста...

Comment: Я не понял фразы "не может стоять позади (сразу после) января". Почему после-то? Вроде перед.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой, ну чтобы дышать кому-то в спину, нужно стоять _сразу после_ него, так ведь? Вы же не можете дышать мне в спину, стоя передо мной? Ведь именно в таком смысле в этом стихотворении употреблена такая метафора? Декабрь дышит в спину январю, словно человек,  который стоит позади (сразу после) кого-то и дышит ему в спину (заметьте, именно здесь, если представить себе календарный год на бумаге, возникает логическая ошибка, но она устраняется, если представить себе ту ситуацию, которая описана мной на картинке). Декабрь дышит в спину январю, стало быть, стоит _сразу после_?

Comment: Почитал Ваш другой ответ [не сразу понял, что это тоже Вы :))], и присоединяюсь к Екатерине. Действительно, всё там отлично и правильно изложено! Вот только насчёт после и перед я плохо понимаю Ваше представление. :( Согласен, что чтобы дышать в спину, надо стоять после физически, как на Вашей картинке. Но никак не могу понять, почему это можно понять и как после по времени. А так, всё остальное вполне для меня понятно. То есть тут не пример с очередью, где последний декабрь дышит первому (предыдущему) январю в спину, а конечно же следующему, наступающему в Новом году.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой, что ж, второй пример как дополнение. Вторым примером пытался разъяснить суть первого. Если первый Вас удовлетворил, то второй можно и не брать во внимание. :)

Answer (score 0):

Представим идущих друг за другом месяцы, как идущих друг за другом людей. Допустим, первый выходит ноябрь, за ним, дыша ему в спину, декабрь. За декабрём же, дыша тому в спину, идёт январь. Не наоборот же?
Или так можно представить. Вот начинается декабрь. Появляется лицом, проходит мимо, и вот уже мы видим его спину (он заканчивается). В это время появляется лицо января, а мы ещё видим спину уходящего декабря. То есть именно январь дышит в спину уходящему декабрю, а не наоборот.

Мне кажется, что декабрю абсолютно без разницы, кто там ему дышит в спину. Ведь это будущее, которое ещё не наступило, но скоро наступит. А дышит в спину ему январь, так как наступает после декабря. "И декабрю январь уж дышит в спину" — по-моему, так будет правильнее.